# read a text field in Python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have text file, like

```
FILED AS OF DATE:       20090209
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20090209
```

I need to find the position using `FILED AS OF DATE:` and read the date. I know how to do it using python strings. But using a regular expression seems cooler:)

Btw, how to parse the date?

Thanks!

Comment: *“but using a regular expression seems cooler”* – ouch! If you worry about your code not being “cool” enough, then you may have other problems ;-)

Comment: I think _may_ is not necessary here :)

Comment: Didn't someone say, "People have a problem, they decide to use regular expressions and now they have two problems"

Comment: -1: No code sample of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime, fileinput, re

for line in fileinput.input():
    if 'FILED AS OF DATE' in line:
       line = line.rstrip()
       dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, 'FILED AS OF DATE:       %Y%m%d')

       # or with regex
       date_str, = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
       dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')

       print dt.date()
```

Example:

```
$ ./finddate.py input.txt
```

Output:

```
2009-02-09
```

Comment: Get just the numbers. Good simple idea, but I think that adding a little comment will make the post even better!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
/FILED.*([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/
```

Search for FILED then anything then parses date divided in 3 groups.

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need to use `RE` for this.

Regarding parsing date, you can use [datetime.strptime(date_string, format)](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Then you can convert it from `datetime.datetime` to `datetime.date` if required.

Alternatively use [python-dateutil parse() function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2), which is quite handy when the format of your date(time) value is not fixed.